# How can we know we still have associated stash for a branch in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've been using TortoiseGit in my ruby on rails project.

Take this for my problem example:

1. I worked on a main branch called "master".
2. later on I branched out to another branch called "demo"
3. so, I kept working on "demo" branch for a while and came some edit.
4. Once I finished editing that branch, I decided to save everything in to stash for "demo" branch. so, I could come back and work on it later on.
5. Next, I subsequently switched back to continue working on "master" again.

my question is here: when I finished working in "master" again this time, I decided to switch to "demo" branch again. up to this point, how can I know there was still some stash associated with the "demo" branch?
    you know after having long been working in a branch, there might have been some possibility that we might have forgot what we did or have in another branch easily.
 I just couldn't wrap my head around this. Is there anything that can remind developers in more systematic way?

any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to TortoiseGit, but if you open up the command prompt and switch to your project's home directory, you can issue a `git stash list` command to view any stashes you have saved. Keep in mind that they aren't directly related to the branch they get stashed on. You can apply a stash that you saved on a branch (say demo) onto another branch (such as master). This is handy for when you start work on the wrong branch and want to apply those changes in another branch to separate your work.